# What is --> symbol in Java?

Tags: java, operators

Recently, I came across a code where --> was used.

example:

```
int a = 5;
while(a-->0){
    //do something 'a' times
}
```

Is `(a-->0)` equivalent to `(a-- > 0)` or simply, `((a=a-1) > 0)`?

If not, I want to know what's that operator called, and are there other similar operators. If so, then where are they mentioned?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's two operations. The postfix `--` (`a = a - 1` but effective on the next line) and a greater than. It's equivalent to something like

```
while (a > 0) {
    a = a - 1;
```

Comment: Ya, I guessed so!! The confusion stemmed from Intelij where, sometimes anonymous Runnables are folded with -> symbols!!

Comment: I think the language(s) should mark this as an error. Operators should be space delimited unless connected to a literal or name.